# numpy -Create a 4 x 4 matrix and add values 4,5,6 above the parent diagonal

Tags: python, numpy

Create a 4 x 4 matrix and add values 4,5,6 above the parent diagonal.I'm unable to understand how to achieve this output. Tried diagonal method but failed. I want the output as shown below.

```
            [[0 4 0 0]
             [0 0 5 0]
             [0 0 0 6]
            [0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [120]: np.diag([4,5,6],1)
Out[120]: 
array([[0, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: What kind of context does it need? It does the job, and the function is documented.

Comment: Your answer landed in VLQ. As per best practices I just suggested a step to make the content useful the future readers.

Comment: Evidently someone is more concerned with appearance than content of my post.  Given the title and minimal tags I don't expect many future readers.  The context provided by the question is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is active or not, but I found a different, bit complicated way to achieve the same and just wanted to share with you guys.(I am a beginner Python user):

```
mat1 = np.zeros((4,4))
list1 = [4,5,6]

for i in range(mat1.shape[1]):
        for j in range(mat1.shape[0]):
            if i<len(list1) and i==j:
                mat1[i][j+1] = list1[i]
print(mat1)
```